# Visible property fails when making worksheets visible after having made charts visible?

Tags: vba, excel

The following code works:

```
Sub ShowSheets(vSheets() As Variant)

    Dim i As Long

    'Make worksheets visible
    For i = LBound(vSheets, 1) To UBound(vSheets, 1)
        If TypeName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1))) = "Worksheet" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vSheets(i, 1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
    Next i

    'Make chart sheets visible
    For i = LBound(vSheets, 1) To UBound(vSheets, 1)
        Debug.Print (TypeName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1))))
        If TypeName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1))) = "Chart" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Charts(vSheets(i, 1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

While the following code fails:

```
Sub ShowSheets(vSheets() As Variant)

    Dim i As Long

    'Make chart sheets visible
    For i = LBound(vSheets, 1) To UBound(vSheets, 1)
        Debug.Print (TypeName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1))))
        If TypeName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1))) = "Chart" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Charts(vSheets(i, 1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
    Next i

    'Make worksheets visible
    For i = LBound(vSheets, 1) To UBound(vSheets, 1)
        If TypeName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1))) = "Worksheet" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vSheets(i, 1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

It fails with the error message:

```
Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)'

Method 'Visible' of object '_Worksheet'failed
```

The only thing that is different between the code that succeeds and the code that fails it that in the code that succeed I first check Worksheets and then Charts, while in the code that fails I reverse that order. It is always the first Worksheet after a Chart that causes the failure.

Why does the second code fails?

Further information: The circumstances are identical in both scenarios. `vSheets(i, 1)` always equates to sheet names. The worksheets and workbook are not protected.

EDIT: Here is the calling routine

```
Sub ToggleSheets()
    'Save sheets in tToggleSheets.DatabodyRange
    Dim wksTables As Worksheet
    Dim loSheets As ListObject
    Dim vSheets() As Variant
    Dim bAnySheetVisible As Boolean

    Set wksTables = GetSheetByCodename(ThisWorkbook, "wTables")
    Set loSheets = wksTables.ListObjects("tToggleSheets")
    vSheets = loSheets.DataBodyRange

    'Check if all sheets are hidden
    bAnySheetVisible = AnySheetVisible(vSheets)

    If bAnySheetVisible = True Then
        'If any is visible, hide all
        Call HideSheets(vSheets)
    Else
        'Else unhide all
        Call ShowSheets(vSheets)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As a matter of interest why do you use two loops anyway?

Comment: Also why not store the Sheet objects themselves, rather than a string representing their names? This would probably simplify your code a lot. And why do you treat Worksheets and Charts separately? Why not just treat them as Sheets?

Comment: You have not posted the code in which *vSheets()* is **Dim'ed.**    Is it an array of strings or an array of *Objects?*

Comment: @Rory: I just had one loop when I started. But when the client added a Chart sheet, my code inexplicably started working. I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working, but when I handled all Worksheets first and Charts after, it worked.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: It's a variant array that holds the names of worksheets. The variant array is created based on user input in Excel.

Comment: Was the original code using `Sheets` in all instances, or `Worksheets`?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: It's a variant Dim vSheets() As Variant.

Comment: @Rory: Yes, the original code was using Sheets for all instances

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your posted code.  My sub *MAIN()* runs your code "as is."

*MAIN:*

1. hides all Sheets (both work and chart) except the first sheet
2. issues a *MsgBox* to verify the hidden state
3. calls your routine

```
    Sub ShowSheets(vSheets() As Variant)

    Dim i As Long

    'Make chart sheets visible
    For i = LBound(vSheets, 1) To UBound(vSheets, 1)
        Debug.Print (TypeName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1))))
        If TypeName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1))) = "Chart" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Charts(vSheets(i, 1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
    Next i

    'Make worksheets visible
    For i = LBound(vSheets, 1) To UBound(vSheets, 1)
        If TypeName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1))) = "Worksheet" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vSheets(i, 1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
Sub MAIN()
    Dim vvSheets(1 To 8, 1 To 1) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, msg As String

    msg = ""
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If i > 1 Then
            Sheets(i).Visible = False
        End If
        vvSheets(i, 1) = Sheets(i).Name
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & Sheets(i).Name
    Next i
    MsgBox msg

    Call ShowSheets(vvSheets)
End Sub
```

Your code ran without error.  I suspect that the error may be associated with how the array is **Dim'ed** or filled in the calling routine.

My initial configuration:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried creating a new workbook and using the same VBA code, including the same VBA code for dimming vSheets. I can't recreate the problem. I have no idea what is causing the problem in the original file. I really would like to know. Unfortunately I can't upload it to the public domain. I appreciate your idea that maybe it had to do with how vSheets was dimmed. But as far as I could test, that wasn't it.

Comment: Not to my knowledge *(but I am only a Student)*

Comment: You seem like a very good student. I am curious, if I may ask, who is Gary?

Comment: Gary was the person who taught me Excel.